# How to wait for all the async to finish?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I have a list of requests that i want to do and i want to wait for all of them to finish in order to procceed. I am using kotlin coroutines with repeat and async like below.

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repeat(serverAccountList.size) { 
                async { 
                    createHelloRequest(it)  // suspend function
                }
            }



            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                _isLoading.value = false
            }
        }
```

How can i join them so i can continue my code inside Main Dispatcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Dispatchers.IO` to call suspendable (non-blocking) functions. All your code can stay on the `Main` dispatcher. Also, use `coroutineScope` to `launch` as many subtasks as you need and Kotlin will ensure all are complete before the `coroutineScope` call completes.

All put together, your code should look like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    _isLoading.value = true
    coroutineScope {
        repeat(serverAccountList.size) {
            launch { createHelloRequest(it) }
        }
    }
    _isLoading.value = false
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn t i call IO Dispatcher for suspendable functions?

Comment: The real question is, why _should_ you use it. The main point of using async networking APIs wrapped into suspendable functions is that you avoid heavyweight native threads that do nothing but sit waiting for a blocking operation to complete. The `IO` dispatcher is there only as a workaround for the unfortunate ones who are stuck with a blocking network API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `await` for your async - e.g.

```
...

val stuff = async {...}
stuff.await()
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repeat(serverAccountList.size) { 
            // save all job handles to mutable variable
            jobs += async { createHelloRequest(it) }
        }

        // await on all jobs
        jobs.awaitAll()   

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
    }
```